# ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application with Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to this technology. i am going to create a new ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application with oracle Database.

Can any one guide me to do this Application. I'm willing to learn. and also i'm working on client side. its very urgent.

If you have any samples or reference. please provide me it will be very helpful to develop our application.

The Technologies will be ASP.NET MVC and Language C#, and ORACLE Datebase.

the database already created. So we have to use this Database and do our module or taks.

Please provide ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. Two points to start with:

1) Look at using ASP.NET MVC 3 if at all possible. It's newer, cleaner, and has a better view engine. There's no reason to start a project in MVC 2 unless you have a corporate legacy reason to do so. Your use of MVC 3 (or 2) should be largely independent of Oracle for everything but the database tier.

2) Microsoft recommends using the Entity Framework for data access; however, Oracle's Entity Framework implementation is not out of beta yet, and they do not recommend you use it in production. You can download the ODT package from Oracle for Visual Studio (and the Oracle EF beta), which will then let you follow most of the tutorials out there for MVC3 and Entity Framework, but you'll be running a risk with beta software. Otherwise, you'll have to use native ADO.NET or an ORM tool like NHibernate.

Comment: Actually this is our client Requirement. we can't able to change the requirement. Please provide me a sample at any type.